# Symfony Form - Custom Button Type can't read property

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm working with Symfony Form in Symfony 5.4 and I need the following:

I have a DTO with some properties. In our application, the default ButtonType has some special handling in the theme-twig (special container with special classes around the button).

Now I need another custom Button-Type to give this new tyoe his own special theme-handling.

I have built the following code for this:

Custom ButtonType-Class:

```php
class FormAddButtonType extends AbstractType
{
    public const BLOCK_PREFIX = 'formaddbutton';

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'button blue-button',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return self::BLOCK_PREFIX;
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ButtonType::class;
    }
}
```

Now I add two buttons to my form:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('test_button_1', ButtonType::class, [
        'label' => 'Test Button 1',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'button blue-button',
        ],
        'row_attr' => ['class' => 'noborder'],
    ]);

    $builder->add('test_button_2', FormButtonType::class, [
        'label' => 'Test Button 2',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'button blue-button',
        ],
        'row_attr' => ['class' => 'noborder'],
    ]);
}
```

The first Button will be rendered without any problem. But the second button (my custom button type) will cause the following error:

`Can't get a way to read the property "test_button_2" in class "My\Name\Space\Dto\MyDataDto"`.

Yeah, this class / object doesn't have a property called "test_button_2". But "test_button_1" doesn't exist either and this button works just fine. Manually setting "'mapped' => false" doesn't work either.

If I add my FormAddButtonType inside of my custom Collection Type via POST_SET_DATA-listener, there is no problem. But if I try to use it in the "main form", it won't work.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still searching for answer:

Your custom form type needs to implement `\Symfony\Component\Form\ButtonTypeInterface` or `\Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButtonTypeInterface`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ButtonTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class YourCustonButtonType extends AbstractType implements ButtonTypeInterface
{
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            //...
        ]);
    }
    
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        //...
    }
    
    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ButtonType::class;
    }
    
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'your_block_prefix';
    }
}
```

Form builder will internally check if your form type implements one of the above interfaces and if so, it will use special `ButtonBuilder` / `SubmitButtonBuilder` instead of generic `FormBuilder`, which is trying to map your field to the object you are passing to the form

Answer (score 0):

add

```php
"mapped" => false
```

in the field option, it stands for "this field doesn't exist in the entity".

I think it does work with the default ButtonType as they probably set it on the

```php
$resolver->setDefaults([ /* ... */ ]);
```

method

doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped